# when using cssgrid, pageYOffset doesn't work when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

im having a bit of a problem.

Im trying to make some element hide, when the user scrolls down. But i having a weird issue/problem. When I use the function pageYOffset, i keeps showing 0, like im not scrolling on the page. I think i may be because of the use of cssgrid (still new to this). you can see my problem [here my cssgrid site](http://7357.dk/cssgrid/).

Here on my test site is show update the "scroll counter" when scrolling but it only does it when i scroll negativ (< 0).

Anyone else that have dealt with this problem or have a solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not actually scrolling the page.
You have your wrapper element set to whatever height the page is minus the header.
That wrapper overflows and you can scroll but on that element, you're not actually scrolling the page.
leave the height of the container to auto and this will scroll the page itself. otherwise look for a different strategy for listening to scrolls inside the wrapper.

Comment: Oh, that makes totally sense - thanks, i will try a different approach then.

Comment: I fixed by adding to the <header>, z-index and position fixed